# How to get a perpendicular segment inside of a triangle

Tags: geometry

I created a graphic to obtain a triangle with three vertices.

The code is as follows:

```
a = {4, 2, 1}; b = {1, 0, 1}; c = {1, 2, 0};

Graphics3D[{
Text[Style["A", Large, Bold, Red], {4.28, 2.09, 1.05}],
Text[Style["B", Large, Bold, Red], {0.86, -0.25, 1.08}],
Text[Style["C", Large, Bold, Red], {0.81, 2.18, -0.15}],
Blue,
PointSize[.05], Point[a], Point[b], Point[c],
Black,
Line[{a, b, c, a}]
}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

What would be the coordinate on the segment BC which forms another perpendicular segment through the point A?

Comment: I was already doing it. the smartphone is slower. :)

Comment: You mean the projection of `A` onto `BC`?

Comment: Yes. This projection forming 90 degree with BC.

Comment: Have you seen [`Projection[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Projection.html)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `b` as the origin:

```
p=Projection[a - b, c - b] + b;
```

Which is the same as:

```
p = ((a - b).(c - b) (c - b))/EuclideanDistance[b, c]^2 + b;

Graphics3D[{Text[Style["A", Large, Bold, Red], {4.28, 2.09, 1.05}], 
  Text[Style["B", Large, Bold, Red], {0.86, -0.25, 1.08}], 
  Text[Style["C", Large, Bold, Red], {0.81, 2.18, -0.15}], Blue, 
  PointSize[.05], Point[a], Point[b], Point[c], Point[p], Black, 
  Line[{a, b, c, a}], Thickness[0.02], Red, Dashed, Arrow[{b, p}], 
  Arrow[{a, p}]}]
```

[image]

Check:

```
Dot[p - b, a - p]
```

> 0

Answer (score 1):

## 1. find the equation of the line through $b$ and $c$

```
a = {4, 2, 1};
b = {1, 0, 1};
c = {1, 2, 0};

line = t b + (1 - t) c;
```

## 2. find the shortest distance from $a$ to this line

[image]

```
p = line/.Last@Minimize[EuclideanDistance[{1, 2 (1 - t), t}, a], t]
```